# multiply table td value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table with quantity cell as editable when change quantity it need to multiply with other parent td value.Here is my code
(i.e) if i change quantity to 2 then the parent rows need multiply by 2

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.quantity').on('change, keyup',function(){
  var tbvalue=$(this).parents('td').val();
    console.log(tbvalue);
    var val=$(this).val();
    var result=tbvalue*val;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Table calculation</h2>
  <p>Calculaton</p>            
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>value1</th>
        <th>value2</th>
        <th>value3</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="quantity" type="number" contenteditable>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td type>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="quantity" type="number" contenteditable>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td class="quantity" type="number"  contenteditable>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `var tbvalue=$(this).text();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.Get the text from each td using this `$(this).text();` and multiply that with input value

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.quantity').on('change, keyup',function(){
       var val=$(this).text();
 if(val =='' ||  isNaN(val) || val < 1){
 return;
 }
      $(this).siblings().each(function(){
          var tbvalue=$(this).text();
          
          var result= parseInt(tbvalue)*parseInt(val);
          
          $(this).text(result);
      })


 
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Table calculation</h2>
  <p>Calculaton</p>            
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>value1</th>
        <th>value2</th>
        <th>value3</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="quantity" type="number" contenteditable>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td type>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td class="quantity" type="number" contenteditable>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td class="quantity" type="number"  contenteditable>1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The quantity value also getting calculated how to fix it

Comment: @HarishKarthick  no it will not work if at the time of editing the field you empty the value and then go for change. it will produce NAN always

Comment: @AlivetoDie He has to write the validation for that.Anyways i have updated the answer.

Comment: @XYZ iam trying to calculate the column values its also working fine but when press any key (i.e: up & down arrow ) it keep on adding how to fix it here is my code ( https://jsfiddle.net/hahkarthick/42gv9qu6/4/ )

Comment: @XYZ ya i checked it when i give 10 & press arrow keys it keeps on multiplying ,disable arrow key in that field  will help or any other method

Comment: @HarishKarthick Avoid the class total from calculating for sum.When you give 10 each time it is updating the row by multiplying with 10.you can disable arrow Or avoid mulitiplying if the value has not changed

Comment: @HarishKarthick https://jsfiddle.net/avhc7qyL/1/ Or save the previous value in input and  avoid multiplying if that value is same with current input

Comment: @Sujith one more q.e ,i analyze your code its working fine & how to i bring previous value to tables if i delete the quantity

Comment: @HarishKarthick Save previous values Somewhere(ex: in a data attribute).And take value from there and reset